# sharepoint 2010: javascript rest api not returning full decimal values, truncating to tenth

Tags: 2010, javascript, jquery, rest

I have a list with a several columns that have number values to fourth decimal place, and I am using javascript com to get data via rest GET request and following simple callback

```
function onGetScoreCallback(response, eventArgs) {
  var thisData = JSON.parse(response.get_responseData());
  for ( var i = 0; i < thisData.d.results.length; i++ ) {
      $('.selector').text(thisData.d.results[i].Score);
  }
}
```

Simple. Only I've noticed the value is truncated to the tenth. So I just viewed the source at
the ListData.svc/MyList and the xml is showing all the values truncated (not rounded) to the tenth for everything....

Is this normal limitation of this type of approach or am I just missing something. I have been unable to find info on this anywhere.

Comment: JSOM COM get list items working though...switched to that however I am still curious about this....?

Comment: No idea why but this magically resolved itself. I didn't change anything and all of a sudden all decimal places (3 for each) started coming back again. even in xml. ???

Comment: was this happening on-prem or on O365?

Answer (score 1):

The value of a return type is formatted as per the WSS default for all fields or that content type.

"Decimal Places Mirrors the Number of decimal places setting in Windows SharePoint Services."

http://office.microsoft.com/en-gb/access-help/import-from-or-link-to-a-sharepoint-list-HA001230313.aspx

The only possible answer is that someone altered this unknowingly and it either got altered back by a reactivation of a feature which includes that content type, or it being set back.